# Convert a val to barcode.js and display the barcode

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the value I get into val and pass it to the codebar string and display the value in bar code. I need the variable text to be converted to barcode

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
    var text = $('#text').val();
    $('#showVal').text(text);  
$("#bcTarget").barcode(text, "ean13"); 
   }); 
   
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" id="button" name="click">
<div id="showVal"></div>
<div id="bcTarget"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode/jquery-barcode.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text" value="123456787654" />
<input type="button" id="button" name="click" value="Convert" />
<div id="showVal"></div>
<div id="bcTarget"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
      var text = $('#text').val();
      $("#showVal").text(text);  
      $("#bcTarget").barcode(text, "ean13"); 
    });
    $("#button").click();
  });
</script>
```

I made it work by, first, finding a source for the jquery-barcode plugin and using it like a cdn. After that, I made sure that I am converting valid input to be converted into barcode. Apparently, 12 char string consisted of numerals is the valid input.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying to get it when I enter the value in the input text this convert it to a bar code I thought it was some mistake of mine but check with an alert that the variable text shows it to me I do not know what I'm doing wrong , These are my first steps in jquery, could you give me more help, Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you be more specific in what help you're asking for. If you want to make the barcode working, just copy the code and make sure that the value you are converting into barcode is valid.

Comment: I need to turn what deposits for example if I deposit 00320123123123 this number one converts it to barrras code or any other one I number what I have achieved up to the moment it is alone the number appears but I could not have achieved that one Converts it to bar code, Apologies for the inconvenience thanks for your support

Comment: Do not input a series of numbers that is less than 12 in length.

Comment: Thank you for your help, thank you very much JD Hrnnts

Comment: Please check this [link](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse370/01au/minirproject/theBarCoders/barcodes.html) for more information about barcode encoding.